# Extract Only Dialogue arrays from DT table

Tags: r

I have a DT table as shown below. Can we extract the square root of diagonal numbers.

```
df
Col A   Col B   Col C   Col D   Col E
A        45     45      45      45
B        46     46      46      46
C        36     36      36      36
D        21     21      21      21
```

Sqrt of the diagonal numbers

```
ColA    Sqrt(Dia)
  A     SQRT(45)
  B     SQRT(46)
  C     SQRT(36)
  D     SQRT(21)
```

Expected Output

```
ColA    Sqrt(Dia)
A      6.708203932
B      6.782329983
C      6
D      4.582575695
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, .(ColA, SqrtDIA = sqrt(diag(as.matrix(df[, -1]))))]
```

Or in `base`:

```
data.frame(ColA = df[, 1], SqrtDIA = sqrt(diag(as.matrix(df[, -1]))))
```

Output:

```
   ColA  SqrtDIA
1:    A 6.708204
2:    B 6.782330
3:    C 6.000000
4:    D 4.582576
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
library(purrr)

setDT(df)
num_cols <- names(df)[map_lgl(df, is.numeric)] 
df[, sqrt_diag := map2(.SD, seq_len(nrow(df)), ~sqrt(.x[.y])), .SDcols = num_cols]
df[, .(Col_A, sqrt_diag)]
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).